# Add Twitter Bootstrap icon to Input box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can we add a Twitter Bootstrap icon `icon-search` to the right of a text input element?

The following attempt placed all the icons inside the input element, how can we crop it so it only displays the icon for `icon-search`?

**Current Attempt**

[image]

**CSS**

```
input.search-box {
    width: 180px;
    background: #333;
    background-image: url('/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png');
    background-position: -48px 0;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    border: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

#### Updated Bootstrap 3.x

You can use the [**`.input-group`**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) class like this:

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

#### [Working Demo in jsFiddle for 3.x](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Z4ntn/)

---

#### Bootstrap 2.x

You can use the [**`.input-append`**](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms) class like this:

```html
<div class="input-append">
    <input class="span2" type="text">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

#### [Working Demo in jsFiddle for 2.x](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/R7Kzx)

---

Both will look like this:

[image: screenshot outside]

If you'd like the icon **inside** the input box, like this:

[image: screenshot inside]

Then see my answer to [Add a Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input Box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839305/1366033)

Comment: If not give solution for bootstrap 4 and if yes then edit the question.

Answer (score 15):

### Bootstrap 5 with 3 different way.

---

1. **Icon with default bootstrap Style**
   [image: Icon with default bootstrap Style]

   ```
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
   </div>
   ```
2. **Icon Inside Input with default bootstrap class**
   [image: Icon Inside Input with default bootstrap class]

   ```
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control border-end-0" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
      <span class="input-group-text bg-transparent"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
   </div>
   ```
3. **Icon Inside Input with small custom css**
   [image: Icon Inside Input with small custom css]

   ```
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-end" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
      <span class="icon-inside"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
   </div>
   ```

Custom Css

```
.icon-inside {
              position: absolute;
              right: 10px;
              top: calc(50% - 12px);
              pointer-events: none;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-size: 1.125rem;
              color: #c4c3c3;
              z-index:3;
            }
```

```css
.icon-inside {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: calc(50% - 12px);
      pointer-events: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-size: 1.125rem;
      color: #c4c3c3;
      z-index:3;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container">
    <h5 class="mt-3">Icon <small>with default bootstrap Style</small><h5>
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
       <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
    </div>

    <h5 class="mt-3">Icon Inside Input <small>with default bootstrap class</small><h5>
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control border-end-0" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
       <span class="input-group-text bg-transparent"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
    </div>

    <h5 class="mt-3">Icon Inside Input<small> with small custom css</small><h5>
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-end" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
       <span class="icon-inside"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
    </div>

    </div>
```

### Bootstrap 4.x with 3 different way.

---

1. **Icon with default bootstrap Style**
   [image: Icon with default bootstrap Style]

   ```
   <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
         <div class="input-group-append">
           <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
         </div>
       </div>
   ```
2. **Icon Inside Input with default bootstrap class**
   [image: Icon Inside Input with default bootstrap class]

   ```
   <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control border-right-0" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
         <div class="input-group-append">
           <span class="input-group-text bg-transparent"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
         </div>

   </div>
   ```
3. **Icon Inside Input with small custom css**
   [image: Icon Inside Input with small custom css]

   ```
   <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-right" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
           <span class="icon-inside"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
       </div>
   ```

Custom Css

```
    .icon-inside {
          position: absolute;
          right: 10px;
          top: calc(50% - 12px);
          pointer-events: none;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-size: 1.125rem;
          color: #c4c3c3;
          z-index:3;
        }
```

```css
.icon-inside {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: calc(50% - 12px);
      pointer-events: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-size: 1.125rem;
      color: #c4c3c3;
      z-index:3;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container">
    <h5 class="mt-3">Icon <small>with default bootstrap Style</small><h5>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h5 class="mt-3">Icon Inside Input <small>with default bootstrap class</small><h5>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control border-right-0" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text bg-transparent"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h5 class="mt-3">Icon Inside Input<small> with small custom css</small><h5>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-right" placeholder="From" aria-label="from" aria-describedby="from">
        <span class="icon-inside"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the first one because of simplicity and also because of the password managers (auto fill was covering the icon in the second one) Thank you for the nice, simple examples.

Answer (score 1):

Since the glyphicons image is a sprite, you really can't do that: fundamentally what you want is to limit the size of the background, but there's no way to specify how big the background is. Either you cut out the icon you want, size it down and use it, or use something like the input field prepend/append option (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms and then search for prepended inputs).

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap 4

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/Ef482ioz42)

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 4.x**

With Bootstrap 4 (and Font Awesome), we still can use the **`input-group`** wrapper around our **`form-control`** element, and now we can use an **`input-group-append`** (or **`input-group-prepend`**) wrapper with an **`input-group-text`** to get the job done:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="my-search">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="my-search"><i class="fas fa-filter"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

It will look something like this (thanks to [KyleMit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366033/kylemit) for the screenshot):

[image]

Learn more by visiting the [Input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

### Bootstrap 5

According to [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#forms)

> .input-group-append and .input-group-prepend. You can now just add
> buttons and .input-group-text as direct children of the input groups.

Example:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-text">File input</div>
    <input class="form-control" id="formFile" type="file" />
    <button class="btn border" type="button" style="background-color: #e9ecef;">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

[image]