# Add Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input Box

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

How can I add a glyphicon to a text type input box? For example I want to have 'icon-user' in a username input, something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is my alternative solution (for 2014) 
JSFiddle [ http://jsfiddle.net/rcotrina94/cyCFS/272 ]

Comment: late to the party but check out my answer, im using only bootstrap to get that effect, and to change color and border i'm using two lines of css. it solves the other issues that were discussed in the answer section http://stackoverflow.com/a/40945821/2914407

Answer (score 794, accepted):

## Without Bootstrap:

We'll get to Bootstrap in a second, but here's the fundamental CSS concepts in play in order to do this yourself.  As [beard of prey points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19918345/1366033), you can do this with CSS by absolutely positioning the icon inside of the input element.  Then add padding to either side so the text doesn't overlap with the icon.

So for the following HTML:

```html
<div class="inner-addon left-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

You can use the following CSS to left and right align glyphs:

```css
/* enable absolute positioning */
.inner-addon { 
    position: relative; 
}

/* style icon */
.inner-addon .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* align icon */
.left-addon .glyphicon  { left:  0px;}
.right-addon .glyphicon { right: 0px;}

/* add padding  */
.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
.right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }
```

### [Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5D8fv5o5egpKpYz509O3?p=preview)

[image: css screenshot]

> **Note**: This presumes you're using [glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/), but works equally well with [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).
>   For FA, just replace `.glyphicon` with `.fa`

---

## With Bootstrap:

As [buffer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23229817/1366033), this can be accomplished natively within Bootstrap by using [**Validation States with Optional Icons**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation).  This is done by giving the `.form-group` element the class of `.has-feedback` and the icon the class of `.form-control-feedback`.

The simplest example would be something like this:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
```

**Pros**:

- Includes support for different form types (Basic, Horizontal, Inline)
- Includes support for different control sizes (Default, Small, Large)

**Cons**:

- Doesn't include support for *left* aligning icons

To overcome the cons, I put together this [pull-request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14194) with changes to support left aligned icons.  As it is a relatively large change, it has been put off until a future release, but if you need these features **today**, here's a simple implementation guide:

Just include the [**these form changes in css**](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/ZrnnkFR3Yv9HGQHrRMiW/formChanges.css) (also inlined via hidden stack snippet at the bottom)
<sub>***LESS**: alternatively, if you are [building via less](http://less2css.org/), here's the [form changes in less](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/ZrnnkFR3Yv9HGQHrRMiW/formChanges.less)</sub>

Then, all you have to do is include the class `.has-feedback-left` on any group that has the class `.has-feedback` in order to left align the icon.

Since there are a lot of possible html configurations over different form types, different control sizes, different icon sets, and different label visibilities, I created a test page that shows the correct set of HTML for each permutation along with a live demo.

### [Here's a demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZrnnkFR3Yv9HGQHrRMiW?p=preview)

[image: feedback screenshot]

> **P.S.** [frizi's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/#comment31018049_18839305) of adding `pointer-events: none;` has been [added to bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14104)

**Didn't find what you were looking for**? Try these similar questions:

- [Add Twitter Bootstrap icon to Input box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16875617/1366033)
- [Put search icon near textbox bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24682653/1366033)

#### Addition CSS for Left Aligned feedback icons

```css
.has-feedback .form-control {
  padding-right: 34px;
}
.has-feedback .form-control.input-sm,
.has-feedback.form-group-sm .form-control {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.has-feedback .form-control.input-lg,
.has-feedback.form-group-lg .form-control {
  padding-right: 46px;
}
.has-feedback-left .form-control {
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 34px;
}
.has-feedback-left .form-control.input-sm,
.has-feedback-left.form-group-sm .form-control {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.has-feedback-left .form-control.input-lg,
.has-feedback-left.form-group-lg .form-control {
  padding-left: 46px;
}
.has-feedback-left .form-control-feedback {
  left: 0;
}
.form-control-feedback {
  line-height: 34px !important;
}
.input-sm + .form-control-feedback,
.form-horizontal .form-group-sm .form-control-feedback {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px !important;
}
.input-lg + .form-control-feedback,
.form-horizontal .form-group-lg .form-control-feedback {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px !important;
}
.has-feedback label.sr-only ~ .form-control-feedback,
.has-feedback label.sr-only ~ div .form-control-feedback {
  top: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-inline .inline-feedback {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .form-inline .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
    top: 0;
  }
}
.form-horizontal .has-feedback-left .form-control-feedback {
  left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: See my edit, I've made the css selector of focusedInput more explicit, otherwise it gets overwritten by .input-group-addon.

Comment: @MichelMüller, I'm not sure I see the value in your suggested edit.  The `.focusedInput` class is defined after `.input-group-addon` so when the Style Sheets **Cascade** down, the latter styles should take precedence.  Can you describe the scenario better which led to this being an issue?

Comment: I think you're right, sorry for the confusion. I think I had an update glitch related to browser cache that lead me to believe it wouldn't pull that css selection.

Comment: I suggest adding "pointer-events: none;" for icons, because by default they interfere with input focusing.

Comment: @RichardCotrina, that looks like it's own separate solution.  You should add an explanation for it and move it to a new answer. I'd upvote it as an answer!

Comment: @Leandro, [**It sure does!**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/7656Q/1/). It's just because FontAwesome introduced breaking changes in Version 4.  If you want to upgrade from [3.x](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/examples/) to [4.x](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/), you have to change `<i class="icon-user"></i>` to `<i class="fa fa-user"></i>`.  Anytime you're thinking about updating external libraries, be sure to read the release notes and new documentation to determine if your app is still compatible or needs to be upgraded.

Comment: @Leando, you can read more about the [new naming conventions in FA 4.0](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/whats-new/#new-naming) as well as a [full migration guide from 3.21 to 4](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4)

Comment: In Bootstrap 3.0 `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>`

Comment: Any way of making the icon inside the input clickable?

Comment: @cwarny, sure, just add [`cursor: pointer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) so it appears clickable, and then listen to the [jQuery `click` event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on the `.form-control-feedback` class.  [**Here's a demo in fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyCFS/1161/)

Comment: The icon not aligned in the middle for input.input-lg

Comment: @Akam, can you provide an example or screenshot or code or any more info that just that.  It shouldn't take much to fork the existing code, but I can't repro based on your comment.

Comment: Adding just a clickable event doesn't work in this instance. You need to add `pointer-events: initial;` to the class for the form-control-feedback so the event bubbles through.

Answer (score 66):

The **official** method. No custom CSS required :

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess4"></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess4">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/yajf3b7q

This demo is based on an example in Bootstrap docs. Scroll down to "With Optional Icons" here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

[image]

Comment: +1 - Definitely nice to have a native approach built into bootstrap.  Although this doesn't do so hot at left aligning icons like the question calls for, but definitely a good approach.

Comment: Adding `{left:0}` to glyphicon class should take care of left alignment. http://jsfiddle.net/LS2Ek/30/ . I like your outline + box-shadow approach though. Looks neat !

Comment: That's originally what I thought too, but you're going to wind up re-creating a lot of the CSS work in different situations.  If you [add a label](http://jsfiddle.net/LS2Ek/31/), you'll see [some problems](http://i.imgur.com/fcrSggJ.png).  On an inline form, `left:0` no longer identifies the start of the input.  Also you'll need to add padding to the left of the input, and remove it on the right. Still, a very nice and clean solution.  I think identifying the left of the input is the hard part, which is where a wrapper with `position:relative` comes in handy.

Comment: You should add this patch to bootstrap. It's a handy and frequently used feature.

Answer (score 45):

Here's a CSS-only alternative. I set this up for a search field to get an effect similar to Firefox (& a hundred other apps.)

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chetfarley/WK3Q6/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <input class="form-control" type="search" />
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-control {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.form-control + .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 8px 27px;
}
```

Comment: +1 great solution.  I adapted it into a left and right utility class, but definitely the right approach

Comment: yeah, so simple and just perfect

Answer (score 14):

It can be done using classes from the official bootstrap 3.x version, without any custom css.

Use `input-group-addon` before the input tag, inside of `input-group` then use any of the glyphicons, here is the code

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
          <input class="form-control left-border-none" placeholder="User Name" type="text" name="username">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the output

[image]

To customise it further add a couple of lines of custom css to your own custom.css file (adjust padding if needed)

```
.transparent {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.075);
 }
 .left-border-none {
    border-left:none !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.075);
 }
```

By making the background of the `input-group-addon` transparent and making the left gradient of the input tag to zero the input will have a seamless appearance. Here is the customised output

[image]

Here is a jsbin [example](https://jsbin.com/bufoxe/16/edit?html,css,output)

This will solve the custom css problems of overlapping with labels, alignment while using `input-lg` and focus on tab issue.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I did it using only the default bootstrap CSS v3.3.1:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Start:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="start-date">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="start-date"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you are using **Fontawesome** you can do this :

```
<input type="text" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome"  placeholder="&#xf007;" />
```

**Result**

[image]

The complete list of unicode can be found in the [The complete Font Awesome 4.6.3 icon reference](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 8):

This 'cheat' will work with the side effect that the glyphicon class will change the font for the input control.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WK3Q6/50/)

```
<input class="form-control glyphicon" type="search" placeholder="&#57347;"/>
```

If you want to get rid of the side effect you can remove the "glyphicon" class and add the following CSS (There may be a better way to style the placeholder pseudo element and I've only tested on Chrome).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WK3Q6/57/)

```
.form-control[type="search"]::-webkit-input-placeholder:first-letter {
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
}
.form-control[type="search"]:-moz-placeholder:first-letter {
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
}
.form-control[type="search"]::-moz-placeholder:first-letter {
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
}
.form-control[type="search"]:-ms-input-placeholder:first-letter {
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
}
```

Possibly an even cleaner solution:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WK3Q6/59/)

**CSS**

```
.form-control.glyphicon {
    font-family:inherit;
}
.form-control.glyphicon::-webkit-input-placeholder:first-letter {
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
}
.form-control.glyphicon:-moz-placeholder:first-letter {
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
}
.form-control.glyphicon::-moz-placeholder:first-letter {
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
}
.form-control.glyphicon:-ms-input-placeholder:first-letter {
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control glyphicon" type="search" placeholder="&#57347; search" />
<input class="form-control glyphicon" type="text"  placeholder="&#57352; username" />
<input class="form-control glyphicon" type="password"  placeholder="&#57395; password" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a non-bootstrap solution that keeps your markup simple by embedding the image representation of the glyphicon directly in the CSS using base64 URI encoding.

```css
input {
  border:solid 1px #ddd;
}
input.search {
 padding-left:20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position-y: 1px;
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAASCAYAAABb0P4QAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAADbSURBVDhP5ZI9C4MwEIb7//+BEDgICA6C4OQgBJy6dRIEB6EgCNkEJ4e3iT2oHzH9wHbpAwfyJvfkJDnhYH4kHDVKlSAigSAQoCiBKjVGXvaxFXZnxBQYkSlBICII+22K4jM63rbHSthCSdsskVX9Y6KxR5XJSSpVy6GbpbBKp6aw0BzM0ShCe1iKihMXC6EuQtMQwukzPFu3fFd4+C+/cimUNxy6WQkNnmdzL3NYPfDmLVuhZf2wZYz80qDkKX1St3CXAfVMqq4cz3hTaGEpmctxDPmB0M/fCYEbAwZYyVKYcroAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
```

```html
<input class="search">
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
input {
  border:solid 1px #ddd;
}
input.search {
 padding-left:20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position-y: 1px;
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAASCAYAAABb0P4QAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAADbSURBVDhP5ZI9C4MwEIb7//+BEDgICA6C4OQgBJy6dRIEB6EgCNkEJ4e3iT2oHzH9wHbpAwfyJvfkJDnhYH4kHDVKlSAigSAQoCiBKjVGXvaxFXZnxBQYkSlBICII+22K4jM63rbHSthCSdsskVX9Y6KxR5XJSSpVy6GbpbBKp6aw0BzM0ShCe1iKihMXC6EuQtMQwukzPFu3fFd4+C+/cimUNxy6WQkNnmdzL3NYPfDmLVuhZf2wZYz80qDkKX1St3CXAfVMqq4cz3hTaGEpmctxDPmB0M/fCYEbAwZYyVKYcroAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
```

```html
<input class="search">
```

Comment: great "jugad" but that is really useful to set custom icon also.thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to do it by placing the glyphicon using the [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo element in CSS.

### [Working demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcotrina94/cyCFS/272/)

For this HTML:

```html
<form class="form form-horizontal col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <span class="usericon">
                <input class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Username" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Use this CSS (*Bootstrap 3.x and Webkit-based browsers compatible*)

```css
.usericon input {
    padding-left:25px;
}
.usericon:before {
    height: 100%;
    width: 25px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    content: "\e008";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

As @Frizi said, we have to add `pointer-events: none;` so that the cursor doesn't interfere with the input focus. All the others CSS rules are for centering and adding the proper spacing.

The result:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

### You can use its Unicode HTML

So to add a user icon, just add `&#xe008;` to the `placeholder` attribute, or wherever you want it.

You may want to check [this cheat sheet](https://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com).

Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="&#xe008; placeholder..." style="font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings', Arial">
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="&#xe008; value..." style="font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings', Arial">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="&#xe008; submit-button" style="font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings', Arial">
```

> Don't forget to set the input's font to the Glyphicon one, using the
>   following code: `font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings', Arial`, where
>   **Arial** is the font of the regular text in the input.

Answer (score 2):

#### Tested with Bootstrap 4.

Take a `form-control`, and add `is-valid` to its class. Notice how the control turns green, but more importantly, notice the checkmark icon on the right of the control? This is what we want!

Example:

```css
.my-icon {
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + .75rem);
    background-image: url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/svgs/regular/calendar-alt.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right calc(.375em + .1875rem);
    background-size: calc(.75em + .375rem) calc(.75em + .375rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-5">
 <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control my-icon" placeholder="Select...">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, good day, where did you get this link? https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/svgs/regular/calendar-alt.svg I can't get similar link for the other icons.

Comment: Ah, don't recall. But, the trick will work, you can use any icon so long as it's from the 5.8.2 release. You can see those icons here: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&v=5.8.0,5.8.2

Answer (score 1):

I also have one decision for this case with Bootstrap 3.3.5:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <label for="date">
       <input type="date" placeholder="Date" id="date" class="form-control">         
    </label>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar col-sm-pull-2"></i>
</div>
```

On input I have something like this: 
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it works in pure Bootstrap 5:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>iconbutton</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center m-4 border rounded">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-search mx-2"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Search">
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

To remove the border that appears on focus, add `shadow-0` to the input.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with existing bootstrap classes and a little custom styling.

```
<form>
    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">
            <i class="icon-user"></i>
        </span>
        <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="Username" style="background-color: #eeeeee;border-left: #eeeeee;">
    </div>
```

**Edit**  The icon is referenced via the `icon-user` class. This answer was written at the time of Bootstrap version 2. You can see the reference on the following page: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#images

Comment: Not seeing the bootstrap glyphicon reference in this answer

Comment: @Kirby, the icon is referenced via the icon-user class.  This answer was written at the time of Bootstrap version 2.  You can see the reference on the following page - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#images

Answer (score 0):

If you are fortunate enough to only need modern browsers: try css transform translate. This requires no wrappers, and can be customized so that you can allow more spacing for input[type=number] to accomodate the input spinner, or move it to the left of the  handle.

```
    @import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");


.is-invalid {
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.is-invalid-x {
  font-size:27px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color: red;
  top: initial;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}




 <h1>Tasty Field Validation Icons using only css transform</h1>
    <label>I am just a poor boy nobody loves me</label>
    <input class="is-invalid"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign is-invalid-x"></span>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPRmNq?editors=110