# Add Glyphicon inside an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm integrating jquery-validation with glyphicons. Basically when the user inputs something correctly I'd like to see the glyphicon inside the input box, like so:

[image: screenshot]

But I'd like it to become something that is triggered via the `CSS :after` property. I can't get anything to work, even with content set to "QDQWDQWD" or some random string. The `:after` element doesn't appear in Inspect element. Am I doing the right approach or can this be solved easier with another solution? (BTW, this is in Rails, if that add something.)

**Markup**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control valid" id="user_email" 
           name="user[email]" placeholder="Email-Address"
           size="30" type="email" value="a@aa5305.com">
</div>
```

**SASS**:

```css
input.valid{
    color: green; /* This works. The text does become green */
    &:after {
        /* content: "<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-star"></span>";*/
        content: "QDQWDW";
        color: green;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 12px;
        top: 12px;
    }
}
```

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Blake Mann, certain elements like `input, textarea, img` are called replaced elements and `:after` and `:before` are not supported for these elements.

Since jquery validation plugin adds `valid/error` class based on validation passes/fails. We can manipulate our css as shown in fiddle. Just change the class from valid to error OR from error to valid to see the change.

On more change in HTML is we need to add extra `span` at the end of each `input`.

http://jsfiddle.net/9RsCS/1/

```css
input.valid {
    color: green;
    width: 200px;
}
input.error {
    color: red;
    width: 200px;
}
.form-group {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
.form-group > .valid + span,
.form-group > .error + span {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 2px;
}
.form-group > .valid + span:after {
    content: "\2713";
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Mahesh. Yeah I like this. The problem though is that some items on the form are grouped inside a form group. Would JavaScript help?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that you cannot use `:after` with an input element. Certain elements, such as `img` or `input` are called "replaced elements", which are not compatible with this type of pseudo-selector.

Instead, you can put those styles on the div surrounding your input. Setting the div to `position: relative;` will allow you to position the checkmark absolutely, relative to that div. Setting your input to be as wide as the div, and then setting the div to control the width of both will make sure that the absolutely positioned element always stays within the input.

Here's an example using a modified version of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/9RsCS/

Comment: Thanks Blake, I never knew about replaced elements.

Comment: How do you achieve this by using jQuery?