# Unable to add an icon at left of an input box in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a [login page here](http://matricole13.tk/college/account.php?login) and I want to add the icon `glyphicon-eye-open` inside the password input field on the right, but I am unable to do so.

I tried putting it inside `.has-feedback` but it didn't work.
I tried the solution to  [Add Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box), but that didn't work as well.

There might be an external style-sheet causing the problem, but I'm unable to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the icon inside of `#password`:

```
<div class="form-group " id="password">
    <input placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control input-field" type="password"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
</div>
```

Then use the following CSS:

```
#password {
    position: relative;
}

#password input[type="password"] {
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#password .glyphicon {
    right: 65px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
}
```

Comment: I want To display it in right side

Comment: Nevertheless, I've edited it to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Using [bootstrap's native validation states](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) is definitely preferable to writing custom CSS here.

When using `.has-feedback`, make sure you also add the class `.form-control-feedback` to the glyphicon.  It should look like this:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label">Username</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" /> 
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/cyCFS/926/)

[image: screenshot]

For more info, see my answer to [adding a Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input Box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839305/1366033)