# Bootstrap sprite image css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to use bootstrap icon image 'glyphicons-halflings.png'

I tried this and couldnt make it to work. Any ideas?

```
.icon-search{
    background: url(/components/bootstrap/3.2.0/img/glyphicons-halflings.png);
    background-position: -44px 10px;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {  
    background: url(/components/bootstrap/3.2.0/img/glyphicons-halflings.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: 14px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you are, or are not using bootstrap? with bootstrap just use `<span class="glyphicon {glyphicon-you-want-here}"></span>`, or if you don't want to use bootstrap look at the calculated css that happens when you do that.

Comment: i want the search image as a background to text box...hence im trying to use it as a css

Comment: so basically you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/86P3S/), right? that would make your question a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box)

Comment: Thank you... How can I mark your answer as correct?