# Icon in input field Laravel 4 / Blade

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-4, icons, laravel-blade

I'm trying to put an icon into my input fields in blade, to look like this

[image]

But don't succeed. I've handled to put an icon to a button:

```
{{ HTML::decode(Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> Send', array('class' => 'btn'))) }}
```

This is how I added it to the input:

```
{{ HTML::decode(Form::text('From','<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> '.Input::get('from'),array('class' => 'myclass', 'id' => 'fromform'))) }}
```

Gives this output:

[image]

Not what we are looking for...

I've tried to add the icon in the labels and inputs, but nothing worked. Anyone an idea?

Comment: That code should work fine. What output are you getting?

Comment: The code works excellent on a button, but I want the icon in an input, there it isn't working. One second, I'll edit

Comment: take a look at this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box)

Comment: Thanks, @Razor I know it's no problem with pure HTML, but need a solution for blade

Comment: I will create a [macro](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#custom-macros) in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Razor I finally got it working, even though this might be a workaround:

Setting a macro like this:

```
  {{ Form::macro('myField', function($name, $value = null, $id = null, $class){        
     return '<div class="inner-addon left-addon">
             <i class="glyphicon '.$class.'"></i>
             <input type="text" name="'.$name.'" class="myclass" id="'.$id.'" value="'.$value.'"  />
             </div>';
     }); 
  }}
```

Call the input:

```
 {{ Form::myField('From',Input::get('from'),'fromform', 'glyphicon-check') }}
```

---

and I took the css out of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box):

```
/* enable absolute positioning */
.inner-addon { 
    position: relative; 
}

/* style icon */
.inner-addon .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* align icon */
.left-addon .glyphicon  { left:  0px;}
.right-addon .glyphicon { right: 0px;}

/* add padding  */
.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
.right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }
```

If someone knows another way to achieve it, I'm happy to hear!

Answer (score 0):

HTML/Blade

```
 <label class="block clearfix">
 <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" value="">
 <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
 </span>
 </label>
```

Sample 
[image]

Hope this help. :)