# Is it posible to make an input checkbox a Bootstrap glyphicon?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Is it posible to make an input checkbox a Bootstrap glyphicon?

I want to make up the default checkboxes with a nice Bootstrap glyphicon.
For example: `glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked` and when checked: `glyphicon glyphicon-check`.

I've tried this:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  content: "\e157";
}
```

But nothing happened..

I don't know if that's posible?

Comment: You can only use the content property for the css pseudo elements ::before and ::after. These are not supported for all html elements.

Comment: Hmmm: http://jsfiddle.net/ayywjrmo/

Comment: It's not really working right? The `::before` and `::after` aren't working..

Comment: It looks like there are 3 good answers here and they all offer a solution. Given that it is possible to add content from a font/icon resource as long as you map them to the pseudo ::before and ::after elements. And then you can toggle the icon used based on modern css techniques which are outlined below. If I get chance I will make a jsfiddle, but I think the answers below should more than cover your requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that in a couple of methods:

**Method 1**

- inside a `<label>` tag, two `<tags>` that represent the icons that you want need to be placed(or outside, per use scenario)
- then toggle these two `<tags>`, when the `input[type='checkbox']` is checked or unchecked
- done.

**Method 2**

- a cleaner approach to the above one, would be to use the css from bootstraps icons, and place them in a `:before`(or `:after` depending on your scenarion) on the `<label>` tag
- then toggle the `content` prop. of the `:before` class, that the icons that you want have, when the `input[type='checkbox']` is checked or unchecked
- done.

---

Check out the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qcf9fous/2/)** and also, a couple of more through documentation on this matter:

- [Add boostrap icon to input boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box/18839305#18839305)
- [Boostrap checkbox documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios)

Comment: Just wondering.. I'm following the bootstrap convention of placing the label before the input in the html. Of course then it does not work as the + in the css selects the next one. Can I use it in a way to keep the label before the html?

Comment: Yeah I guess so, you could try to possibly add inside the `label` the input and take it from there, maybe theres some combo you can use

Answer (score 6):

If you're able to modify your markup a bit, this should do:

```
<label for="myCheckbox" class="glyphy">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" /> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
    label words
</label>

$('.glyphy').click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('input')) { // prevent double-event due to bubbling
        $(this).find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-check glyphicon-unchecked');
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nx7hhm4n/6)

Answer (score 1):

if you have the icons, you can style it as such:  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/164/

```
/*hide checkbox and radio buttons*/
input[type=checkbox], 
input[type=radio] {
    width: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    opacity: 0; /*This is the part tht actually hides it*/
}

/*normalize the spacing*/
input[type=checkbox] + label,
input[type=radio] + label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -2em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

/*unchecked css*/
input[type=checkbox] + label > span,
input[type=radio] + label > span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/Face-sad.svg/48px-Face-sad.svg.png');
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

/*selected checkbox css*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label > span > span {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display:block;
    background-image: url('http://wscont1.apps.microsoft.com/winstore/1x/a14c3995-34d7-454c-82e2-0c192e48b91a/Icon.173718.png');
}

/*selected radio css*/
input[type=radio]:checked + label > span > span {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display:block;
    background-image: url('http://wscont1.apps.microsoft.com/winstore/1x/a14c3995-34d7-454c-82e2-0c192e48b91a/Icon.173718.png');
}

<div>
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check1" value="check1" />
    <label for="check1"><span><span></span></span>Checkbox</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" />
    <label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span>Radio1</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" />
    <label for="radio2"><span><span></span></span>Radio2</label>
</div>
```