# how to append an icon to an input search?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to append an icon to an input.

with font awesome is possible to attach that icon on the value of the input, like this:

```
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="&#xf090;">
```

where `value="&#xf090;"` is the equivalent of `<i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>`, that is perfect so far, but I need that icon to be bigger, how can I accomplish that ? or what is the other way to attach that icon the input ?

and css

```
input[type="submit"] {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

and the icon must be attached to the left.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box)

Comment: Yisus, @Adrift is not a duplicate, see where I asked: where ```value="&#xf090;"``` is the equivalent of ```<i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>```, that is perfect so far, but I need that icon to be bigger, how can I accomplish that ?

Comment: @Adrift I am asking how to make that I icon bigger on ```value="&#xf090;"``` does not have nothing to do with the other question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `<button type="submit"></button>`

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: FontAwasome;
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff");
}

.sign-in:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwasome;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2.75rem;
  height: 2.75rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}

button {
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  min-height: 2.75em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="sign-in"></button>
```