# bootstrap dateRangePicker icon not showing

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I am trying, with dateRangePicker to have a calendar icon showing in the input box, so the user identify rapidly that this is a date field. [like on this page](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config)

[image]

Unfortunatly, there is no HTML offered for this example so I took the code from the F12 console i tried it in my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 demo">
        <h4>Your Date Range Picker</h4>
        <input type="text" id="dateRange" class="form-control">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

This how it looks on my page.

[image]

Would be fun if it was clear in the doc how to show this icon. It could have been an option to turn on or off this feature, without having to manually add some html in your code.

Please help!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box

Answer (score 1):

use this if you use bootstrap....

```
<div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" data-mask="">
                </div>
```

or see this
https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/pages/forms/advanced.html

think this will help you...

Comment: Yes now I see an icon but it is unclickable... It's not exacly what I'm looking for but for the moment it will do. I lost enough time on this!

Comment: did you use font awesome link or not

Comment: please use onclick to trigger the function