# Google Map V3: Position a Clear X on input search

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to position a clear button on the input to delete the text in Google Map V3.

CSS:

```
#searchclear {
    //Doesn't matter what I put
}
```

General Javascript:

```
 var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var searchclear = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('searchclear'));

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(searchclear);
```

HTML:

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search food, sites, places">                    
<span id="searchclear" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" onclick="clearAllSearch()"></span>
```

I know it has to do with the TOP_LEFT on map.controls, but how do I go about changing it so I can actually use display:inline-block on the remove button?
If I remove the below line, the remove button will be placed outside of the map. `map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(searchclear);`

I can use absolute positioning, but the remove button will scale and break when browser window shrinks or expand.

Any suggestions? I am trying to place the x inside the input, on the right most.

Issue with the TOP_LEFT:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem (preferably a code snippet, a jsfiddle or similar wouldn't hurt also).

Answer (score 2):

You could consider the following approach.

Place icon and input element inside container:

```
<div id="search-container" class="inner-addon right-addon">
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
        <span id="searchclear" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" onclick="clearAllSearch()"></span>
</div>
```

where you can use the following CSS to left and right align glyphs:

```
/* enable absolute positioning */
.inner-addon { 
    position: relative; 
}

/* style icon */
.inner-addon .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* align icon */
.left-addon .glyphicon  { left:  0px;}
.right-addon .glyphicon { right: 0px;}

/* add padding  */
.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
.right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }
```

> Originally this css has been posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839305/1375553)

And finally place controls on map:

```
var searchContainer = document.getElementById('search-container');
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(searchContainer);
```

**Result**

[image]

**Working example**

```js
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
        zoom: 13
    });
    
    var searchContainer = document.getElementById('search-container');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(searchContainer);


    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        infowindow.close();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  
        }
        marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
        }));
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }

        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function clearAllSearch() {
    
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}


.controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 30px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
}

    #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
    }

.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}






.inner-addon {
    position: relative;
}

    /* style icon */
    .inner-addon .glyphicon {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 10px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

/* align icon */
.left-addon .glyphicon {
    left: 0px;
}

.right-addon .glyphicon {
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="search-container" class="inner-addon right-addon">
   <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
   <span id="searchclear" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" onclick="clearAllSearch()"></span>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap"
                async defer></script>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UgTyuhQx5q7GQ5BvMMZk?p=preview)