# Bootstrap glyphicon with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Withour Razor syntax I can use glyphicon like that:

```
<div id="addIndirectCityBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
</div>
```

And it works perfect, glyphicon with textbox using razor syntax as below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.From.City, new { @id = "cityFrom", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "City", @style = "margin-bottom: 10px;" })
```

Where should I use glyphicon to have it in textbox or next to textbox

Comment: What is your requirement. Do you want to show the glyphicon next to text Box?

Comment: next or inside, doesn't matter

Comment: Most solutions will involve either making the outer div appear to be the text box, or absolutely positioning the glyphicon within the parent div and applying a left or right padding to the input. Check out the answers on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box

Answer (score 0):

You can use input group in bootstrap, form-control class will put the object 100% width of box, so you need to group them.

Here is an example

```
<div class="input-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.From.City, new { @id = "cityFrom", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "City", @style = "margin-bottom: 10px;" }
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**How To use Glyphicons in Mvc Using Model**

- **for example :**

**Model**

```
public class Menu
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Menuicon { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Menu m)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = m.Menuicon;
            return View(m);
        }
```

**Index View**

```
@model projectname.Models.Menu

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Name)<br />
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Name)<br />
        @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Menuicon)<br />
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Menuicon)<br />

        <input type="submit" value="Save">
}
<br />

<div>
    <span class="@ViewBag.Message"></span>
</div>
```

**Result**

[image]