# Bootstrap Contact Form 7

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

Iam posting a screenshot of my results with the code and , a screenshot with what results iam trying to do . I tried to embed icons into placeholder but it seems it doesnt work .

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <label>Name</label>
    <div class="form-field">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        [text* name placeholder "Enter your name"]
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <label>E-Mail</label>
    <div class="form-field">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
        [email* email-78 placeholder "Enter your email"]
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <label>Telephone <span style="color:#aaa">(Optional)</span></label>
        <div class="form-field">
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
            [text text-74 placeholder "Enter your phone"]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <label>Website <span style="color:#aaa">(Optional)</span></label>
        <div class="form-field">
            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
            [text text-985 placeholder "Enter your website"]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label>Message</label>
        <div class="form-field">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
            [textarea textarea-197 placeholder "Enter your message"]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        [submit class:btn class:btn-default "SEND YOUR MESSAGE"]
    </div>
</div>
```

My results are : [image: My results]

I want to accomplish this : [image: I want to accomplished]

Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box

Answer (score 0):

Find below example and it may help you.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control iconDsp" placeholder="&#xf007;"/>
```

**CSS**
in below code .iconDsp class which will link FontAwesome font-family to display icon

```
input.iconDsp{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I want to combine it with my Contact Form 7 plugin

Comment: can you provide fiddle what you have created so that i can help you.

Comment: What do you mean fiddle ? My code is on the topic .. ? can you explain me what do you mean please ?

Comment: as you have posted image of design post the same html code, css and its related script