# How to use glyphicon in a form input field?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

How can we use a glyphicon icon inside a input text field?for example-how to use a calender icon in the input text field

Comment: possible duplicated [Put icon inside input element in a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)

Comment: Also you can see this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/cyCFS/) and this Q [Add Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box)

Comment: are you looking for [bootstrap datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) ?

Comment: How to use a calendar glyphicon in a form such that when i click on it....it should display the dates as it displays when i use the input type as date...