# Flask WTF forms adding a glyphicon in a form field

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, wtforms

I have a Flask Wtf form as follows:

```
class URL_Status(Form):
    url = URLField("Enter URL",
                       validators=[url(), DataRequired()],
                       render_kw={"placeholder": "http://www.example.com"},)
    submit = SubmitField('Search', render_kw={"onclick": "loading()"})
```

now I would like to add a bootstrap glyphicon in the input filed i.e. 'url'. As far as I know from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box). We need to write the code as follows:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
```

When I call the form in HTMl my html creates all the code except this line:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
```

Any suggestions how can I add this line from my class 'URL_Status' so that I am able to see a glyphicon with my input field. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box)

Comment: I am not creating forms using HTML. I am creating forms from server side using wtf.

Comment: I solved your problem, give it a try!

Comment: Is the problem solved? If yes, Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little trick to solve this problem.

CSS:

```
.user-icon {
padding-left:30px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position-x: 4px;
background-position-y: 4px;
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);}
```

Template:

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.username(class_="form-control user-icon") }}
    {{ form.password }}
    {{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

This solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29705837/5511849). It just embedding the image representation of the glyphicon directly in the CSS using base64 URI encoding.

You can get base64 data of glyphicon on this [site](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/glyphicons/). Besides, You can also use image(25*25) to replace the base64 data. Like this:

```
background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='user.png') }});
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used wtforms in a while. I think you need a custom widget:

```
class CustomURLInput(URLInput):
    ...
    def __call__(self,....):
        ...
```

Take a look at this https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/9be964158fbcd1af52b345451bbd14751127dd37/wtforms/widgets/core.py#L159
for details.

and your url field:

```
url = URLField(
    "Enter URL",
    validators=[url(), DataRequired()],
    render_kw={"placeholder": "http://www.example.com"},
    widget=CustomURLWidget()
)
```

Or you can do it in your template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jinja2 macros do render a glyphicon with your form, and then import the macro you've created in your current html

Example:
1. create an html (example: "_form_macro.html") file with this macro inside:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}

    <dt>{{ field.label }}
    <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
            <span class="add-on form_input"><i class="icon-calendar fa-border form_input"></i></span>

    {% if field.errors %}
        <ul class=errors>
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    </dd> 
{% endmacro %}
```

2. import the macro in your current html using:

```
{% from "_form_macro.html" import render_field %}
```

3. Use the macro you've created to render your form like this:

```
{{ forms.form_name.label_tag }}
{{ render_field(forms.form_name, type="yourtype", class="yourclass") }}
```

4. Check http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/ for more information about macros