# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - feedback glyphicons are shifted

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

When I put 2 fields in a row, their glyphicons are being shown [with a nasty offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/junfk.png):

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 has-feedback has-error">
    <input data-placeholder="Your Latitude" id="latitude" name="latitude" type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 has-feedback has-error">
    <input data-placeholder="Your Longitude" id="longitude" name="longitude" type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The full JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/v_melnik/f8u9hvLa/6/

Is there a way to make them being shown properly?

Lots of thanks to everyone!

**UPDATE**: Someone marked this question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box). But this question isn't about adding a glyhicon, it's rather about using glyphicons with a "narrowed" input box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box)

Comment: By the way, the fields are being aligned a bit better when I use the `row` class for the outer `div`, but glyphicons are still shifted: https://jsfiddle.net/v_melnik/t3bdhzbk/1/

Comment: @mayersdesign, I have to disagree: my question is not about adding a glyphicon to the input box, it's about its alignment which works fine when the box has the full width and being broken when the box has the `col-*-*` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your html

```
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="col-xs-6">     
      <div class="form-group has-feedback has-error">
        <input data-placeholder="Your Latitude" id="latitude" name="latitude" type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback has-error">
        <input data-placeholder="Your Longitude" id="longitude" name="longitude" type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8u9hvLa/7/)

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be the most suitable (as on my taste) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute` for glyphicon.

```
.glyphicon-remove::before {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/f8u9hvLa/9/)

Answer (score 1):

***only for Mobile Device*** Because you can use `xs` class. **Add Style.**

```
.form-control-feedback
{
  right: 7px;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f8u9hvLa/10/)**

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.form-control-feedback
{
  right: 7px;
}
.
```

```html
<!-- We'll use col-xs-* here, as JSFiddle's result window is really narrow -->
<div class="ibox col-xs-12">
  <div class="ibox-content">
    <form action="#">
      <div>
        <label>Location</label>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-6 has-feedback has-error">
            <input data-placeholder="Your Latitude" id="latitude" name="latitude" type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-6 has-feedback has-error">
            <input data-placeholder="Your Longitude" id="longitude" name="longitude" type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```