# How can I add a font-awesome icon to an input box without bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to include a font-awesome icon into a form input, but I am running into issues finding a solution. Looking on this site only gives questions *with bootstrap*, so I am including one without it. I tried adapting the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839305/1876508) but the alignment is off. How can I fix this?

```css
.inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}
.inner-addon .fa {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.left-addon .fa  { left:  0px;}
.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="inner-addon left-addon">
  <i class="fa fa-adn"></i>      
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what size you want your input to be, you could add additional padding to your input:

```
.left-addon input {
    padding: 8px 5px 8px 30px;
}
```

Or you could reduce the padding on the font-awesome icon:

```
.inner-addon .fa {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```css
.inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}
.inner-addon .fa {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.left-addon .fa  { left:  0px;}
.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }

.inner-addon-tall input {
  padding: 8px 5px 8px 30px;
}
.inner-addon-tall .fa {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="inner-addon left-addon">
  <i class="fa fa-adn"></i>      
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="inner-addon left-addon inner-addon-tall">
  <i class="fa fa-adn"></i>      
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
</div>
```

Or you could do a combination of them both based on the height you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code from this [Add Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box/18839305#18839305) is using the stylesheet from bootstrap so the height of the input is different.The simple way is change the padding value to 3px.

```css
.inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}
.inner-addon .fa {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3px; //Change this
  pointer-events: none;
}
.left-addon .fa  { left:  0px;}
.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="inner-addon left-addon">
  <i class="fa fa-adn"></i>      
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
</div>
```