# Place icon and fix its position inside input control of dynamic width using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic input control whose width changes as per business conditions. The input control is inside a table. Inside the input control is a calendar icon (`glyphicon`), whose margin should also change as per the conditions. It should support responsiveness also. Right now as the input control's width changes, the calendar's position changes and it does not stay in one position. Sometimes's it is inside the input control in the very middle and sometimes its way outside it. Basically, the calendar must be at a dedicated place irrespective of the input control's width.

Right now the code is as such that it works well for 1900x1200 and 1366x768. But it does not work for other resolutions and certain devices. Media query seems to go off in some scenarios. Is there a way that we can fix the calendar position inside the input control and to the extreme right without media query. Jquery/CSS solution will do as long as I do not have to fix the `margin-right` property of the calendar icon for every resolution.

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/23493/)

Below is the code snippet

```css
input.c-text-field[type=text], input[type=email] {
    display: block;
    width: 276px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    outline: 0;
    background: #FFF;
}
.glyphicon {
    float: right;
    width: 36px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -36px;
    color: #0379d3!important;
}
.glyphicon-calendar {
    pointer-events: none;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.glyphicon-calendar:after {
    font-family: MWF-MDL2;
    font-style: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    content: "\E787";
    display: block;
    font-size: 26px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: right;
}
.c-checkbox label.c-label, input.c-text-field[type=text], table .c-checkbox label.c-label {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//assets.onestore.ms/cdnfiles/external/mwf/long/v1/v1.15.0/css/mwf-west-european-default.min.css">
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <!-- I do not want to put margin-right hardcoded like this. It should come dynamically or fix with other CSS properties -->
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="margin-right:15%;"></i> 
<input value="04/29/2018 12:00 AM" class="sfr-ip-start-date c-text-field Control x-hidden-focus" id="StartDate1" type="text" style="cursor: pointer;width:250px;font-size:13px">     
    </td>
    <td>
    <!-- I do not want to put margin-right hardcoded like this. It should come dynamically or fix with other CSS properties -->
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="margin-right:20%;"></i> 
<input value="04/29/2018 12:00 AM" class="sfr-ip-start-date c-text-field Control" id="StartDate2" type="text" style="cursor: pointer;width:170px;font-size:13px">                             
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `position:absolute` ?

Comment: why not considering a backgroud image ... easier

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box Possibly this can help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `position: relative` property to `td` which is parent of `.glyphicon`, and positioned icon in `absoulte` property, so the `.glyphicon` are confined within the `td`. We don't need `margin-right` anymore, so I remove all of them. Set `right` property to decide how far is the `.glyphicon` to the right side of `td`. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqwumpej/1/)

```css
td {
  position: relative;
}

input.c-text-field[type=text],
input[type=email] {
  display: block;
  width: 276px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  outline: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

.glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  width: 36px;
  color: #0379d3!important;
}

.glyphicon-calendar {
  pointer-events: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.glyphicon-calendar:after {
  font-family: MWF-MDL2;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  content: "\E787";
  display: block;
  font-size: 26px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: right;
}

.c-checkbox label.c-label,
input.c-text-field[type=text],
table .c-checkbox label.c-label {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//assets.onestore.ms/cdnfiles/external/mwf/long/v1/v1.15.0/css/mwf-west-european-default.min.css">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- I do not want to put margin-right hardcoded like this. It should come dynamically or fix with other CSS properties -->
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        <input value="04/29/2018 12:00 AM" class="sfr-ip-start-date c-text-field Control x-hidden-focus" id="StartDate1" type="text" style="cursor: pointer;width:250px;font-size:13px">
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- I do not want to put margin-right hardcoded like this. It should come dynamically or fix with other CSS properties -->
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        <input value="04/29/2018 12:00 AM" class="sfr-ip-start-date c-text-field Control" id="StartDate2" type="text" style="cursor: pointer;width:170px;font-size:13px">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```