# Put search icon near textbox using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, icons

I am using bootstrap by default textbox taking full width of column and I want to  put search icon at the end to textbox.

My code is like this:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <input id="txtName" class="form-control input-sm" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to use input group.

Please suggest an alternate way or alternate html with css.

Comment: I think this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429121/inline-form-nested-within-horizontal-form-in-bootstrap-3/23375097#23375097 You have to wrap each element within a `col-xs-#`

Answer (score 118, accepted):

### Here are three different ways to do it:

[image: screenshot]

### [Here's a working Demo in Fiddle Of All Three](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/eu9Lv)

### Validation:

You can use native bootstrap [validation states](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) (*No Custom CSS*!):

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

For a full discussion, see my answer to [Add a Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input Box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839305/1366033)

### Input Group:

You can use the [**`.input-group`**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) class like this:

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

For a full discussion, see my answer to [adding Twitter Bootstrap icon to Input box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16875617/1366033)

### Unstyled Input Group:

You can still use [**`.input-group`**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) for positioning but just override the default styling to make the two elements appear separate.

Use a normal input group but add the class `input-group-unstyled`:

```html
<div class="input-group input-group-unstyled">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then change the styling with the following css:

```css
.input-group.input-group-unstyled input.form-control {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group-unstyled .input-group-addon {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

---

Also, these solutions work for [any input size](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/eu9Lv/4/)

Comment: He mentioned he did not want to use input-group

Comment: @Jim, Yeah, that's why my first suggestion doesn't include it, but other people are likely to hit this question at a later point in time who won't have the same restriction.

Comment: This is true, good thinking. Are you able to provide a solution that does what my example does -- Icon outside of the input element, without using input-group without custom css?

Comment: @Jim, If you don't want something to look like the bootstrap defaults, you're going to have to write CSS at some point.  But you can put the icon *outside* of the search box by using an input-group for layout and then just taking away the input-group styling from the element.  It's certainly *less* custom css, which means less to maintain :)

Comment: @KyleMit, could it be that the fiddle doesn't work with IE11 (the glyphicons are not displaying properly)?

Comment: @HeyJude, I'm just getting burned this month because all my old fiddles used http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js which just cut over to V4 - Updated the Fiddle for 3.3.7 - should work now

Comment: Looks like it does not work for Bootstrap 4; what needs to be changed for that to work?

Answer (score 4):

Adding a class with a width of 90% to your input element and adding the following input-icon class to your span would achieve what you want I think.

```
.input { width: 90%; }
.input-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

**EDIT**
Per dan's suggestion, it would not be wise to use .input as the class name, some more specific would be advised.  I was simply using .input as a generic placeholder for your css

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea since this will make all inputs on the site 90%.  If you want to go this route then you should create a custom class (not generic `input`)

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" name="whatever" id="funkystyling" />
```

Here's the CSS for the image on the left:

```
#funkystyling {
    background: white url(/path/to/icon.png) left no-repeat;
    padding-left: 17px;
}
```

And here's the CSS for the image on the right:

```
#funkystyling {
    background: white url(/path/to/icon.png) right no-repeat;
    padding-right: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I liked @KyleMit's answer on how to make an unstyled input group, but in my case, I only wanted the right side unstyled - I still wanted to use an input-group-addon on the left side and have it look like normal bootstrap. So, I did this:

css

```
.input-group.input-group-unstyled-right input.form-control {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group-unstyled-right .input-group-addon.input-group-addon-unstyled {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

html

```
<div class="input-group input-group-unstyled-right">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-unstyled">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in pure CSS using the :after pseudo-element and getting creative with the margins.

Here's an example, using Font Awesome for the search icon:

```css
.search-box-container input {
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
}

.search-box-container:after {
    content: "\f002";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!-- font awesome -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="search-box-container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."  />
</div>
```