# how to put a mic symbol inside a textbox in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

created a text box in asp .net , and want to put a mic symbol inside that text box. whenever the user clicks on that mic symbol need to perform some operation. tried to put placeholder, but placeholder hides when enters some text .

Comment: How would you do this using plain HTML?

Comment: i would like to put mic symbol as the google search bar

Comment: Looks like a job for bootstrap check out [this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682421/put-search-icon-near-textbox-bootstrap