# bootstrap - insert glyphicon next to input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to insert an icon next to an inout type was was able to do it using this code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="accountSpan">Account name</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-unstyled">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="accountSpan">something</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="account name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="accountInput">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
            </span>
       </div>
</div>
```

and this css

```
            .input-group.input-group-unstyled input.form-control {
                -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                        border-radius: 4px;
            }
            .input-group-unstyled .input-group-addon {
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 0px;
                background-color: transparent;
            }
```

which I found in this thread [Put search icon near textbox using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682421/put-search-icon-near-textbox-using-bootstrap)

But the given css changes the formating of the addon which results in

[image]

What is is I am missing? Thanks

**Update**

Removing background-color: transparent; will result in the addon having a border to

[image]

Comment: Try to remove this: `background-color: transparent;` and `border: 0px;`

Comment: Could you specify how are you expecting to have styled. The code just work also without this styles, just loading _Bootstrap_.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @C0dekid.php, see my update.

Comment: @LionelT thanks for your reply, I updated my OP :)

Comment: What are you trying to say, that you want the addon with the icon ? without a color or the something addon ?

Comment: @C0dekid.php Yep that solved it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your 2nd selector to

```
input-group-unstyled .input-group-addon:last-child {
    ...
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/o1x3ubab/

Comment: Thaks. Just a quick question. What is syntax doing? is it like inheritance? .input-group-unstyled .input-group-addon:last-child {

Comment: without `:last-child` that styles would be applied for all the `.input-group-addon` elements (i.e. both the label and the icon). `:last-child` tells the browser to apply the style only if the element is the last element in its wrapper (i.e. only for the icon)

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="col-sm-4 input-group">
   <input class="form-control">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button  class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
   </button>
   </span>                                                </div>
```

Comment: it's the simplest way to do so

Comment: The simplest way is what @potatopeelings recomended, but thanks for your input :)