# Icon after text box in Bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am trying to display an icon after a text box within a `form-horizontal` Bootstrap form. So I set my text-box width to `80%` and added the icon.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tag, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tag, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 80%" } })
        <img id="tag-status" src="~/Content/Images/alert.png" style="display: inline" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tag, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this places the icon below the text box.

[image]

Looking further, I see that the `form-control` class includes `display: block`. If I remove that, it displays how I want.

[image]

But I'm concerned that removing the block style may cause display issues on some devices.

Does anyone know if there's there a Bootstrap way to do what I want?

Comment: It's basically been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682421/put-search-icon-near-textbox-using-bootstrap

Comment: @ZimSystem: That's very similar and I will study that question in more detail, but it doesn't seem to be running into exactly the same issue that I am.

Comment: Looks exactly like the same situation as input-group-unstyled in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24682653/171456 .. it will require a custom implementation of sorts.

Comment: You can check out the Boostrap method of adding icons with input groups here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: Utilize grid system like `<img class="col-xs-2">` or trying adding `bootstrap icons` instead of img

Answer (score 2):

Set icon position to absolute and make sure the form-group class position is relative

```css
.form-group{
  position: relative
}

.form-group img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 0px;  
}
```

This will position the image above the text field if you want it to be side by side just give the right property a negative value `right: -5px`

or use the bootstrap way (mentioned in the comment) which uses `input-group` class to customize the look and feel.

Comment: But you're changing the `form-group` class, which would affect every form on the site for every device. Isn't that was I've said I'm trying to avoid?

Comment: I do not think this will affect the default behavior, but to make sure you can wrap this specific snippet in a custom class container and prepend that class to the css rule. Or add another class to the form-group div and set it to relative

Comment: Well question is for a bootstrap solution and I'm afraid that's not the one.