# Bootstrap 5 box-shadow is overlapping in input-group

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to modify the css of my input-group and input-group text when input is in focus
In this case i'm using bootstrap 5

But as you can see in the image below. There's some overlapping between input and input-group-text

So far this is my implementation

CSS:

```
.input-group:focus-within .input-group-text {
        border-color: #ced4da;
    }
    
    .input-group:focus-within .form-control:focus~.input-group-text {
        transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
        border-color: #80bdff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-6">
    <label for="password" class="required control-label col-form-label text-md-end">Kata sandi</label>
    <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Masukkan kata sandi" autocomplete="off">
         <span class="input-group-text rounded-end"><i class="eyepass eyeCross"></i></span> @error('password')
         <div class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                 <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
          </div>
     @enderror
</div>
```

THE RESULT :

[image]

Try to add some padding to input-group-text but seems like not working

**UPDATE:**

Based on HDP answer the box shadow's look better.
But somehow, the shadow left and right padding is looks much bigger than the default size

[image: updated answer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set focus box shadow as below css.

```
.input-group:focus-within .input-group-text {
    border-color: #ced4da;
}
.input-group:focus-within .form-control:focus~.input-group-text {
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    border-color: #80bdff;
    box-shadow: 0.30rem 0 0 0.25rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}
.input-group:focus-within .form-control:focus{
    box-shadow:-0.25rem 0 0 .25rem rgba(13,110,253,.25)
}
.input-group:focus-within .form-control.is-invalid:focus{
    box-shadow:-0.25rem 0 0 .25rem rgba(var(--bs-danger-rgb),.25)
}
```

Otherwise, You can use 3rd method from here: [Icon Inside Input with small custom css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875392/add-twitter-bootstrap-icon-to-input-box/51911250#answer-51911250)

Comment: Hello HDP, thanks for the answer. I updates my thread. Based on the css you've given, seems like the box shadow left and right size is bigger than the default bootstrap 5 size. Is it possible to handle that issue?  Try to change the box shadow size by myself but the result is bad, the overlap box-shadow is showing again

Comment: I know, but, there is no more possible. because, have not possible to create only particular any one side shadow. Here, We are create outer box shadow & then move any side. Hope, you are understand.

Comment: @lauwis I have update answer. please try second method. Icon Inside Input with small custom css. Hope, this help.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `outline:none` for input

--

Comment: Please edit your question to further elaborate on how exactly you have solved the problem and why your solution works. (include some relevant code from the original post)

Comment: outline: none in input is not working

Comment: @Rojo The problem is not solved yet

Comment: @lauwis as I can see input type=password when you write something it displays as text - give us reproducible example so we can help you

Comment: @Nevazno_html_css_js_3 it's just because i toggle the eye icon to show the password

Comment: It's possible using this online compiler https://angrytools.com/bootstrap/editor/  to run it  and the overlapping box shadow will show up